# Mongo DB lookup using 3 collections with selected fields in projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections and I am looking for data by joining 3 collections.
I already know how to join 2 collections and get data. Refer below for sample data and aggregation that I already tried with 2 collections

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ncn9HfNI1zk

I am looking for solution to output selected fields from 3 collections like below

invNum (from Invoices)
ruleId, RuleName (From Rules)
fileName (From Files)

Below is the aggregation query that I tried

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "rules",
      "localField": "ruleId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "inventory_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "invNum": 1,
      "name": 1
    }
  }
])
```

But I am getting fields only from invoices collection.

Comment: You can use `$lookup` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree that yes you do need to use `$lookup` twice, there are also a couple of extra steps you need in order to get your documents to `$project` in the shape you want. You can use this:

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "rules",
      localField: "ruleId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "rules"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$rules"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "files",
      localField: "fileId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "files"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$files"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      invNum: 1,
      name: 1,
      ruleid: "$rules._id",
      ruleName: "$rules.name",
      fileName: "$files.name"
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IJeVG9_2Zpg) for a working example.